# How to build Dynamic TSQL query with Begin and End Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK I am not a SQL guru or DBA, so if there was an all together better way of doinf this, then please free to speak up.

However what I need to do specifically is enhance an existing Stored Procedure that uses dyanmic SQL to not insert duplicate values. The SQL on its own when specefic to a single table is a piece of cake. Right now though, I am having trouble with a generic stored proc I have that works generically for several tables and uses TSQL. The problem is with the BEGIN and END statements.

```
    SET @Query =  'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ' + @DescriptionFieldName + ' 
       FROM '+ @TableName +'
       WHERE (' + @DescriptionFieldName + ' = ''' + @DescriptionValue + ''') 

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO '+ @TableName +' (' + @DescriptionFieldName + ', LastUser, LastUpdate) VALUES ('''+ ISNULL(@DescriptionValue, '') +''', '''+ ISNULL(@LastUser, '') +''',Convert(Varchar, GetDate())) '  + 'SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
    END'

EXEC (@Query)
```

When I change the EXEC to a PRINT, everything *appears* to be OK syntax wise, but it gives the following error when using EXEC:

**"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'."**

Does anyone have an idea on how to correct this issue so that the query will work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a missing parenthesis after the where clause.

```
 SET @Query =  'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ' + @DescriptionFieldName + ' 
       FROM '+ @TableName +'
       WHERE (' + @DescriptionFieldName + ' = ' + @DescriptionValue + ') )

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO '+ @TableName +' (' + @DescriptionFieldName + ', LastUser, LastUpdate) VALUES ('''+ ISNULL(@DescriptionValue, '') +''', '''+ ISNULL(@LastUser, '') +''',Convert(Varchar, GetDate())) '  + 'SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
    END'
```

Comment: Yep nice catch - had nothing to do with the BEGIN and END after all. I also had to add (3) tic marks around @DescriptionValue (modified original post for future readers) because it is varchar like so: WHERE (' + @DescriptionFieldName + ' = ''' + @DescriptionValue + ''')). Is the (3) tic method the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, when dealing with on-the-fly dynamic SQL for production or in code generation I like to use templates which makes it a little easier to maintain (note that you can embed line breaks, which is also nice - no forgetting to insert CHAR(13)/CHAR(10) or a need for a space before a quote):

```
DECLARE @template AS varchar(max) = '
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT {@DescriptionFieldName} -- Note this is unnecessary
        FROM {@TableName}
        WHERE ({@DescriptionFieldName} = ''{@DescriptionValue}''
    ) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO {@TableName} ({@DescriptionFieldName}, LastUser, LastUpdate)
        VALUES (''{@DescriptionValue}'', ''{@LastUser}'', ''{@LastUpdate}'');
    END
'

DECLARE @Query AS varchar(max) = @template
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, '{@DescriptionFieldName}', @DescriptionFieldName)
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, '{@TableName}', @TableName)
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, '{@DescriptionValue}', ISNULL(@DescriptionValue, ''))
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, '{@LastUser}', ISNULL(@LastUser, ''))
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, '{@LastUpdate}', @LastUpdate)

PRINT @Query
EXEC (@Query)
```

You still have doubled quotes, but you don't have to add the strings up, it's obvious when you've forgotten to replace a parameter, and you aren't repeating insertions in code when things have to change.

Also note that this may have problem with NULL in @DescriptionValue (your original had the same problem in the WHERE part in the EXISTS)

Note that you can also nest your replaces and with appropriate formatting, it can even be readable:

```
DECLARE @Query AS varchar(max) = @template
SET @Query = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Query
                 ,'{@DescriptionFieldName}', @DescriptionFieldName)
                 ,'{@TableName}', @TableName)
                 ,'{@DescriptionValue}', ISNULL(@DescriptionValue, ''))
                 ,'{@LastUser}', ISNULL(@LastUser, ''))
                 ,'{@LastUpdate}', @LastUpdate)
```

Comment: very nice I like this method as the 'improvement' to my original TSQL. Thank you for speaking up and showing this.

Comment: BTW, when you mention "SELECT {@DescriptionFieldName} -- Note this is unnecessary" I get: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.". I can't just SELECT w/o at least 1 field right? What would you have put instead?

Comment: @atconway You can just do SELECT * (it's not a general no-no to use SELECT * in an EXISTS like it is on a normal SELECT) or SELECT 1.  Meaning there is no need to do any variable insertion.

Comment: @atconway You can also nest your REPLACEs - I didn't for readability in this example.